# Delayed Job Gem: Undefined Method 'perform' for Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am successful with integration [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) with a mailer (app > mailers > notification_mailer.rb), which has a single method:

```
class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"]

  def notification_message(activity, user)
    @user = user
    @activity = activity


    if @activity.is_comment?
        subject = @activity.trackable.user.username + ' commented on ' + @activity.trackable.commentable.project.title
      @type = "comment"
    end

    mail(to: @user.email, subject: subject)
  end

end
```

I call this in my controller, for example:

```
NotificationMailer.delay.notification_message(@activity, user)
```

However, I'm having issues using delayed_job for non mailer jobs. I created a folder in app > jobs where I've placed my classes, such as:

```
class CarrierwaveImageUploader
    def execute(image_id, s3_url)
        if Image.exists?(image_id)
            @image = Image.find(image_id)
            @image.remote_image_path_url = s3_url
            @image.update_column(:rotation, nil)
            @image.save
        end
    end
    handle_asynchronously :execute
end
```

But when I try to call this method in my controller with

```
CarrierwaveImageUploader.delay.execute(@image.id, s3_image_url)
```

I get the error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `execute' for CarrierwaveImageUploader
```

I am using delayed_job 4.1.2 and have restarted delayed_job.

Comment: is execute method is really reachable without creating the instance of CarrierwaveImageUploader class?

Answer (score 1):

`def execute` is an instance method, not a class method.

`CarrierwaveImageUploader.delay.execute(@image.id, s3_image_url)`

Doesn't work because the class `CarrierwaveImageUploader` doesn't have an `execute` method.

```
uploader = CarrierwaveImageUploader.new
uploader.delay.execute(@image.id, s3_image_url)
```

Should work, as it creates an instance and calls its `execute` method.